# How to enable wmqJmsClient-1.1 Feature in Websphere Liberty profile?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, rad, websphere-liberty

Hi we are trying to enable `wmqJmsClient-1.1`,`wmqJmsClient-2.0` feature in Liberty profile . We performed feature Intsall using InstallationUtility and Feature Manager as well.
On Installation it shows:

```
Step 7 of 7: Installation completed
CWWKF1017I: One or more features installed successfully: [wmqJmsClient-2.0].
Start product validation...
Product validation completed successfully.
```

But when we try to access the feature using Rational Software Architect it shows up `Warning: Feature is not available.`
But while accessing the same via eclipse it seems to be working.
What needs to be performed in case you want to use Rational Software Architect to perform the same. RSA version being used : 8.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to refresh the server in RSA. Go to `Servers` view, double click the server, click `Runtime Environment` link, then `Advanced options..` link and finally `Refresh`.

If this wont help, you could try install WebSphere Developer Tools (I didn't try that), run update on RSA , or install newer version as 8.5 is pretty old now.

Comment: Nope does not work in Version 8.5 . Guess will have to try with a Higher Version.